# Que diferencia existe entre API, biblioteca y Framework?

Tags: api, framework7

Son términos muy próximos y ya he encontrado textos que intercambian estos conceptos, como si en determinadas situaciones las definiciones sean casi iguales.

¿Cuales son las definiciones técnicas que distinguen una **API** de una **biblioteca** o un **Framework**?

¿Existen situaciones en que sean permitido intercambiar estos términos sin cometer violar la correcta definición técnica?

Comment: Hola Adolfo. Stackoverflow en español es un sitio un tanto especial y preguntas como las que haces, aunque legítimas, no funcionan en esta comunidad de programadores. Te invito a que conozcas más sobre SOes visitando [esta presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). También te recomiendo que hagas tu investigación en Google o Wikipedia y si tienes un problema puntual, habrá gente aquí con el buen ánimo de ayudarte.

Comment: Tu lo has dicho, no existe un consenso total al respecto. Existen algunas definiciones más aceptadas que otras.

Comment: Es decir, tu pregunta puede dar lugar a una discusión o debate, el cual podría no llegar a nada, incluso confundirte más de lo que estás ahora. Yo te sugiero reformular tu pregunta tal que sea más precisa en tus dudas (y evite la discuesión) o mires wikipedia.

Comment: La pregunta es clara y relevante. Si bien distintas personas pueden entender distintas cosas usando la misma palabra esto es muy muy distinto de una pregunta del tipo ¿Cual es el mejor lenguaje para...? La respuestas a esta pregunta no depende de opiniones, si hay gente que usa una palabra con el significado A y otra con el significado B entonces es un hecho objetivo que esa palabra puede significar tanto A como B dependiendo del contexto y una respuesta completa incluirá ambas definiciones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Una **biblioteca** es un conjunto de elementos (funciones, clases, tipos predefinidos, constantes, variables globales, macros, etc) que es posible utilizar en un programa para facilitar la implementación de ese programa.
- **API** viene del inglés "Application programming interface" que significa "Interfaz para programación de aplicaciones". Es la parte de una biblioteca a la que accede un programa que usa la biblioteca; haciendo así el uso de la biblioteca independiente de los detalles de implementación. Una API puede ser implementadas por distintas bibliotecas.
- Un **framework** es un conjunto integrado de herramientas que facilitan un desarrollo software. Puede incluir APIs y bibliotecas. Pero también puede incluir otros elementos como herramientas de depuración, diseño gráfico, prototipado, edición, etc.

Con frecuencia se usan los términos API y biblioteca indistintamente. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que una API es siempre única (dejando aparte distintas versiones) y que una API  no incluye detalles de implementación. Mientras que una biblioteca no tiene por qué ser única y debe contener una implementación completa. Que una API sea única es muy importante, es lo que permite escribir un programa en C++ para Linux y que ese programa, sin modificar, sirva para Mac si las bibliotecas que usa están disponibles para ambos sistemas.

Un ejemplo de biblioteca es JavaMail de Oracle. Es posible hacer un programa que envíe correos electrónicos programando diréctamente sockets. Pero es mucho más rápido utilizar JavaMail o cualquier otra biblioteca para correos eléctronicos pues estas bibliotecas ya implementan la funcionalidad que necesitas. Además de ser más rápido también es menos propenso a errores, sobretodo en una biblioteca de amplio uso; pues el código es probado por millones de usuarios y la comunidad de desarrollo hará en general un mejor trabajo que el que puede hacer el equipo de un programa individual.

CORBA es una API. Pero puede haber una implementación para Linux, otra para Mac, etc.

Un ejemplo de framework sería Unity3D que ofrece un conjunto de herramientas que facilitan el desarrollo de videojuegos.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, referente a las definiciones técnicas, con eso no creo que haya problemas de respuestas, para lo demás ya si que podria crear confusión.

Una **biblioteca** es una colección de objetos y funciones que sirven para un propósito en particular.

Un **framework** es una colección de patrones para ayudarte en la construcción de una web, app...

Una **API** es una interfaz para otros programas para interactuar con su programa sin tener acceso directo.

En resumen, una **biblioteca** es como un complemento, el **framework** es el esqueleto y la **API** la parte orientada hacia la capa visual para interactuar con ella.